# Inline-block <span> containing a single space is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace

I have an animated `<h1>` in which the subtitle flies in from the right, letter by letter.

The subtitle is divided into 2 parts.

- In the first part (before the bullet), I wish to eradicate all the spaces.
- In the second part (after the bullet), I wish to retain all the spaces.

Curiously though, as the letters and spaces fly in, the on-screen spaces are **invisible**.

Where there are spaces, I want to see the letters visibly separated by those spaces as they fly in.

The spaces *do* exist in the DOM - you can see `<span> </span>` in the DOM Inspector in both Chrome and Firefox. But, despite having a display style of

```
display: inline-block;
```

the spaces show up as zero width on the screen. (And they are grayed-out even in Firebug).

Here is the *jsFiddle*: https://jsfiddle.net/2u6uLn7d/

And here is a working example:

```js
var subtitle = document.getElementsByClassName('subtitle')[0];
subtitle.style.opacity = '0';

function activateSubtitle() {

  if (subtitle.textContent.indexOf('\u2022') !== -1) {
  var bulletIndex = (subtitle.textContent.indexOf('\u2022') - 1);
  var beforeBullet = subtitle.textContent.substr(0,bulletIndex);
  var afterBullet = subtitle.textContent.substr(bulletIndex);
  beforeBullet = beforeBullet.replace(/ /g, '');
  subtitle.textContent = beforeBullet + afterBullet;
  }

  else {subtitle.textContent = subtitle.textContent.replace(/ /g, '');}
  
  var subtitleLength = subtitle.textContent.length;
  var heading = subtitle.parentNode;

  subtitle.style.opacity = '';
  subtitle.style.position = 'fixed';
  heading.classList.add('stilts');

  for (var i = 0; i < subtitleLength; i++) {
  subtitle.innerHTML += '<span>' + subtitle.textContent[i] + '</span>';
  }

  subtitle.innerHTML = subtitle.innerHTML.substr(subtitleLength);

  var eachLetter = 50;
  var allLetters = ((subtitleLength + 3) * eachLetter);

  var i = 0;
  var spans = subtitle.getElementsByTagName('span');

  var enterSubtitle = setInterval(function(){

    if (i > (subtitleLength - 2)) {clearInterval(enterSubtitle);}
    spans[i].style.WebkitTransform = 'translate(0,0)';
    spans[i].style.transform = 'translate(0,0)';
    i++;

  },eachLetter);


  setTimeout(function(){
    
    for (var i = 0; i < subtitleLength; i++) {
      var letter = spans[0].childNodes[0];
      subtitle.insertBefore(letter,spans[0]);
      subtitle.removeChild(spans[0]);
    }

    subtitle.removeAttribute('style');
    heading.classList.remove('stilts');
    if (heading.getAttribute('class') === '') {
      heading.removeAttribute('class');}

  },allLetters);
}


window.addEventListener('load',activateSubtitle,false);
```

```css
h1 {
font-size: 72px;
font-weight: normal;
}

h1 .subtitle {
display: block;
font-size: 36px;
}

.subtitle span {
display: inline-block;
transform: translate(100vw,0);
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<h1><strong>Page</strong> Heading
<span class="subtitle">Subtitle Part 1 &bull; Part Two of the Subtitle</span>
</h1>
```

**N.B.** *I should probably add, if you want to slow the animation down so that you can examine it in a DOM Inspector, change the line*

```
var eachLetter = 50; /* 0.05 seconds */
```

*to something much higher, like:*

```
var eachLetter = 1500; /* 1.5 seconds */
```

Comment: Add `white-space: pre;` into `.subtitle span` block

Comment: Oh what?! It was **that** simple?! That's awesome @BobSponge. Thank you very much indeed. (I've just spent nearly 90mins on this!) If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will upvote and accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent whitespace collapsing you can use css `white-space` property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Here is table of available values from link above:

```
Value       New lines       Spaces and tabs     Text wrapping
==============================================================
normal      Collapse        Collapse            Wrap
nowrap      Collapse        Collapse            No wrap
pre         Preserve        Preserve            No wrap
pre-wrap    Preserve        Preserve            Wrap
pre-line    Preserve        Collapse            Wrap
```

In your case suitable values are `pre` and `pre-wrap`:

```
.subtitle span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(100vw,0);
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: A superbly authoritative answer - thank you very much!